# xarray multi-dimensional data plotting with matplotlib LogLocator

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I have a xarray DataArray object named `da`:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'sm_pct' (month: 12, latitude: 681, longitude: 841)>
array([[[0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0]],

       ...,

       [[0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0]]])
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 -10.0 -10.05 -10.1 ... -43.9 -43.95 -44.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 112.0 112.0 112.1 112.2 ... 153.9 153.9 154.0
  * month      (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

I would like to use matplotlib LogLocator in the xarray DataArray.plot() function with cartopy for basemap.

```
cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r
central_lon, central_lat = 145, -37
p = da.plot(transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), levels=20, cmap=cmap, col_wrap=3, aspect=2, size=4, x='longitude', y='latitude', col='month', subplot_kws={'projection': ccrs.Orthographic(central_lon, central_lat)})
```

The native matplotlib ax.contourf() function has `locator=ticker.LogLocator()` as attribute.

How can I get `locator=ticker.LogLocator()` to work the xarray DataArray.plot() wrapper function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cartopy axes object, which I'd recommend that you create first and then pass it to `da.plot()`'s via the `ax=` keyword argument.

The syntax would be then as following (for x-axis here)

```py
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_lon, central_lat))

p = da.plot(
    ax=ax,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    levels=20,
    cmap=cmap,
    col_wrap=3,
    aspect=2,
    size=4,
    x="longitude",
    y="latitude",
    col="month",
)

ax.gridlines(
    draw_labels=True,
    xlocs=ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0, numticks=5),  # or whatever your LogLocator specs are
    ylocs=ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0, numticks=5),  
)
```

Note that this works only with positive longitudes and latitudes. For negative coordinates you probably have to create a custom `LogLocator` subclass that takes care of that.